# C++ cin questions

Tags: c++, input, cin

This seems to be weird:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {  

    cout << "function main() .." << '\n';  

    char ch = 0;  
    double number_value=1.1;  

    cin >> ch;  
    cin.putback(ch);  

    cin >> number_value;  
    cout << "1 .. " << " " << cin.good() << " " << number_value << '\n';  
    cin >> number_value;  
    cout << "2 .. " << " " << cin.good() << " " << number_value << '\n';  

    return 0;  

}
```

If I input the following:

```
7a 1
```

I get the following:

function main() ..

```
7a 1  
1 ..  1 7  
2 ..  0 0
```

I understand the:

```
1 ..  1 7
```

but why the variable number_value is 0.
`cin.good()` shows failure so nothing would have read and the value in number_value from the previous assignment would remain. I expect the value of 7.

Comment: You can use std::boolalpha to turn those 1s and 0s into true and false.

Comment: Note that `cin.good()` is not the same as `bool(cin)`, and you should prefer the latter when checking for extraction success.  The common idiom of `if (cin >> var)` works this way, too.

Comment: @Roger "bool(cin), and you should prefer": I thought, that even though function-style casts continue to be legal, the named casts were preferable.

Comment: @Alexandros: Sometimes, but not always.  Compare `return some_smart_ptr<T>(new T);`, `return (some_smart_ptr<T>)(new T)`, and `return static_cast<some_smart_ptr<T> >(new T);`, which are all three completely equivalent.  (Note that in this case *some\_smart\_ptr* has an explicit T* ctor, so `return new T;` isn't even an option.)  However, any of those 3 will always give the same results, while `cin.good()` and `bool(cin)` can give different results.

Answer (score 2):

That's what I'd expect too. With the compilers I have handy, the output looks like this:

```
function main() ..
7a
1 ..  1 7
2 ..  0 7
```

You may have discovered a bug in your compiler's standard library.

Comment: Second that output with MinGW...  
function main()\n 
7a 1\n 
1 ..  1 7\n 
2 ..  0 7\n

Comment: Not changing the value is required: 22.2.2.1.2/1 "If an error occurs, val is unchanged; otherwise it is set to the resulting value."